# How do I use regex and jQuery to replace to two seperate strings with two seperate replacement strings?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I'm using jQuery to try something like this:

```
$('input').keyup(function(e){
    var val = $(this).val();

    var smileString = val.replace(/[:][)]/g, '<img src="smile.png" />');
    $('#regexoutput').html(smileString);

    var frownString = val.replace(/[:][(]/g, '<img src="frown.png" />');
    $('#regexoutput').html(frownString);
})
```

Is there a way to do it with one expression? The above code only works for the bottom replace only.

Comment: Have you looked at the api documentation for replace and html?

Comment: @AaronKurtzhals I could not find an entry for replace() but for html(), yes. This technique only works for the bottom replace only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('input').keyup(function(e){
    var val = $(this).val();

    var smileString = val.replace(/[:][)]/g, '<img src="smile.png" />').
        replace(/[:][(]/g, '<img src="frown.png" />');

    $('#regexoutput').html(smileString);

});
```

Comment: Note that if the text is long, the last solution I posted is better beccause it scans the string only once.  This scans twice and generates twice the garbage.  If the string is short, either will work fine.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want

```
$('input').keyup(function(e){ 
    var val = $(this).val(); 

    val = val.replace(/[:][)]/g, '<img src="smile.png" />');  
    val = val.replace(/[:][(]/g, '<img src="frown.png" />'); 

    $('#regexoutput').html(val); 
})
```

You can also do it with one `replace` operation if you make the second arg a function that inspects the match string and returns the correct result.

Untested:

```
val = val.replace(/:\)/g, function (s) { 
        var fn = s == ':)' ? 'smile' : 'frown';
        return '<img src="' + fn + '.png" />' 
      });
```

Comment: This is definitely a smart approach but too specific for my needs.